# setting up Ibm-cloud organization

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, cloud-foundry, organization

setting up Ibm-cloud organization

I was trying to do "ibmcloud cf push" for the simple project that I found in github but it shows me "No org targeted"! I tried to just set the organization that I can find in my account in IBM-cloud> cloud foundry orgs which is my email address so I tried to use "cf target -o ORG" but it shows "Could not get org"!

```
API endpoint:      https://cloud.ibm.com   
Region:            us-east   
User:              XXX@yahoo.com   
Account:           sonia's Account (XXXX)   
Resource group:    Default   
CF API endpoint:   https://api.us-east.bluemix.net (API version: 2.128.0)   
Org:                  
Space:
```

Comment: Was that `cf target -o ORG` or `ibmcloud cf target -o ORG`

Comment: I tried both of them but it didn't work!

Comment: What about `ibmcloud target --cf` ?

Comment: Nope! that one also didn't work! :/

Answer (score 2):

I solved it!!!
first I unset my region and set it to the south-us
after that, I could use those commands for setting the organization and space 

 `ibmcloud target -o Myorg`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to push Cloud Foundry applications in a different region, you can add a space to your org in that region. That way you are then able to target your default org in different regions.

Within the cloud.ibm.com UI navigate to "Manage->Account" and then on the menu on the left select "Cloud Foundry Orgs". You will see a list of Cloud Foundry organizations. If you select an org in the next screen you can add a Cloud Foundry space to that org and choose the region where you want to create the space.

After you have done that you are able to target the CF org and CF space in the new region.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use:

```
ibmcloud target --cf
```

For a friendly menu.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you login to the same region as your account. Use the login passcode  from the console UI profile menu to login and choose the right location. When i did so my org was populated correctly in the CLI.